# Ubuntu-touch 15.10: Installing x11apps without breaking anything

Tags: ubuntu-touch, chroot

So, I have a BQ M10 tablet and would love to install some x11 legacy apps.

The two options I have come across are to do so using chroot or libertine containers.

However on 15.10 it seems that it's not possible to use libertine without remounting the root partition as RW.

Is that the case? Is it basically impossible to install x11 applications without remounting or waiting for OTA-11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From googling around it seems that libertine cannot be used on 15.10 without remounting the root partition.

This may change with OTA-11 which has an eta of sometime next week. (week beginning May 30th).